# SetState call blocks access to field updated by stream

Tags: dart, stream, setstate

I am making a barcode scanning functionality. The camera feed is setting `_currentImage`.

```
// CameraView.dart

  CameraImage _currentImage;
  CameraImage takePhoto() => _currentImage;

  void imageStream(CameraImage image) async {
    print("_currentImage is set with " + image.toString()); // keeps saying it sets 'currentImage'
    this._currentImage = image;
  }
```

Later on I call `takePhoto` from button pressed handler and call 'setState' empty...

```
  void pressedShowBarcodeOnScreenButton() async {
    var image = this.cameraView.takePhoto();
    if (image == null) {
      print(// occurs after having called empty 'setState' every time button is pressed
          "image was null, maybe it is not possible to take images this fast!");
      return;
    }

    var barcode =
        await VisionService.getInstance() // is not producing any errors
            .analyzeBarcode(ImageUtils.toAbstractImage(image));

    if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(barcode)) {
      return;
    }

    print("got barcode: " + barcode); // prints all barcodes ok, but stops doing so when calling 'setState'

    setState(() {
      // Makes it so that 'currentImage' is null at all times, despite continuously set by imageStream given from log
      //this.scannedBarcodes = [...this.scannedBarcodes, barcode]; // my intention eventual to update a list
    });
  }
```

I suspect it might be due to some underlaying dart behavour, or there is some sort of bug? Why does the `setState` call prevent me from accessing the `_currentImage` - or why is blocked from being set by the `imageStream()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `CameraView` which contained the `CameraController` that had the stream, was part of the page to display the barcodes.
So `SetState(){}` triggered a reconstruction of the CameraView, and the controller was not able to be reconstructed. Probably the old stream was producing the log and was misleading.

It helped to extract the `CameraController` in this scenario, and have it accessed as singleton, inside `CameraViewController` that I made:

```
//...
    static CameraController _cameraController;
    static Future<CameraController> getCameraControllerInstance() async {
    if (_cameraController == null) {
      var cameras = await availableCameras();
      if (cameras?.length == 0) {
        print("the device did not have a camera");
        return null;
      }
      _cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
      await _cameraController.initialize();
      _cameraController.startImageStream(updateCurrentImage);
    }

    return _cameraController;
  }
```

And I use it in a `FutureBuilder` like so, in the `CameraView`:

```
FutureBuilder futureBuilder() => FutureBuilder<CameraController>(
      future: CameraViewController.getCameraControllerInstance(), // <--!!!
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CameraController> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingPage();
        }

        return content(snapshot.data);
      });
```

I am tempted to have one instance of the CameraView around at all times (?), since it looks glitchy when updating the list - but as I see it would be anti pattern as the Widget's are supposed to rerender (immutable) themselves:

The content of the page that has the barcode list:

```
Widget content() {
    return Container(
        child: (Column(children: [
      cameraView, // camera view part of page and recontructed on 'scannedProducts' state change
      header(),
      scanButton(),
      Column(
        children: this.scannedProducts(), /// list
      )
    ])));
  }
```